# Editing data in Excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following string in my file cell:

```
"<div class="product-tab"> <div class="product-reviews"> <h4 class="title">Features</h4><div align="justify">......{data}</div></div> </div>"
```

From this string I need to remove:

`"<div class="product-tab"> <div class="product-reviews"> <h4 class="title">Features</h4>"`

from start and then

`"</div> </div>**"`

from last.

I have more than 4000 rows in my file.

Comment: is your example listed on 1 row each? or is it several lines of HTML? If each example is on 1 row, you can use **Substitute` = Substitute(A1,"<div class="product-tab"> <div class="product-reviews"> <h4 class="title">Features</h4>","")**. Then you can wrap that in another `Substitute` function to get rid of the end. **=Substitute(Substitute(A1,"<div class="product-tab"> <div class="product-reviews"> <h4 class="title">Features</h4>",""),</div> </div>**,"")**. If it's a big HTML, you'll probably be best served using some HTLM parser, through maybe VBA.

Comment: Provided that it is that precise string at the beginning of each line, use Right(stringname, len(stringname) - Nchars) where Nchars is the number of characters in the string that you want to remove.

Comment: thanks smottt!! it solved my problem